# New MoBo, Internal Speaker broken or mis-connected?

Tags: audio, motherboard, speakers

I have a new motherboard, MSI H81M-E33. The new case (cooler master elite 110) came with one of those tiny 4-pin speakers, as shown in my picture.

Everything seems to work fine, a fresh Win 7 installation boots without issue, but I get no POST beeps from the MOBO, and there is no sound in after booting-- Windows says that no playback device is available.

Headphones work fine, so it is not all sound, just the little internal speaker that isn't working. MOBO & Chipset drivers all installed & updated, and Device manager shows no problems with any devices.

The image shows the Mobo pins diagrams and the mini speaker. JFP2 is where I have the speaker connected.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is it more likely that its just a bad speaker?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the speaker connector the right way around?  The Black wire should be on pin "1".  That's assuming they wired the buzzer right. ;)  You can safely flip it around and try it the other way without blowing anything up.

Comment: Judging by [their install video for JFP1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPELIdVNZUI) - I think that manual is wrong.  What's the actual silkscreen label on the motherboard for that JFP2 connector show?

Comment: I tried flipping the speaker, in case something was mislabeled-- no change. As for the video, it looks like that's MSI's generic how-to, the board in that video is not mine at all. The silkscreen on mine reflects the diagram above.

Comment: Could jus tbe a defective buzzer.  I'd say try another speaker/buzzer, and/or try that buzzer on another motherboard.

Comment: @techie007 I think your right: I'll try pulling from a known-good system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the angle the picture is taken at, but it looks like the speaker's red and black wires are connected to the outermost pins of that four-pin connector.  On the diagram, the speaker should be connected to pins 1 and 3, not 1 and 4.

If that's the case, you may be able to prise the pins out of the plastic plug and put them in the correct place.

Comment: Browsing around the web, it looks like this 4-pin, 1 & 4, is the standard: 1 & 3 wouldn't send any power (VCC5) least for this board

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help in this problem.
You have to connect the two wires, red and black at the ends.
If removed RAM will see that the speaker works.
Some brands of motherboards have removed the beep OK.
The speaker only works if there is a problem.
I hope I have helped.

Comment: This doesn't really clarify anything.  The author has already tried to connect it, and there should be a beep on start-up without needing to remove RAM.